# How To set named locators for allure report?

Tags: java, allure, selenide

I've saw a video where is possible to set named locators for allure report
to get view $(locatorname).click - passed:

[image: allure report]
There is code:

```
public  class Named extends NamedBy {

    private final By        origin;
    private  String name;

    public Named(By origin) {
        this.origin = origin;
    }

    public Named as(String name) {
        this.name = name;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Objects.nonNull(name) ? name : this.origin.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public List<WebElement> findElements(SearchContext context) {
        return  new Named(By.id(id));
    }

}
```

And code for elements:

```
SelenideElement button = $(id("someid").**as("locatorName")**)
```

and then should be possible to work with this element.

But i can't.

I dont have method as when i try to create selenideElement.

Pls help. such report is mush more readble.

video URL: https://youtu.be/d5gjK6hZHE4?t=1300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example doesn't seem to be valid. At least, a method `as` must return `this`. Moreover, `id` in the overridden `findElements` is missing. Plus, it's not really clear why you extend `NamedBy` instead of `By`.

Anyway, that's just a wrapper around `By`. To see those locators' names in report you have to follow a previous example in a video first (event listener), before completing `NamedBy` implementation.

P.S. To make it works the same way as was introduced in the code snippet, you have to add an additional creational logic, e.g.:

```java
public static NamedBy id(String locator) {
    return new NamedBy(By.id(locator));
}
```